# What are some (if any) methods to handle disabled functions in PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm playing around with a Google App Engine instance and PHP. [Some functions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Disabled_functions) are disabled in this environment. The codebase I'm testing with includes Twig, which uses the `tempname()` function (potentially other disabled functions are used, too).

I know I can alter Twig's codebase to use something else, but I'm loading it via Composer and would prefer not to alter it. Are there any methods for working around this? One thing that comes to mind is declaring the function in a different namespace, but I wonder if there are any other options.

I'm not looking to replicate functions like `exec()`, `passthru()`, etc., only the few functions that return strings that I could easily replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the PHP documentation on overriding system functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

You could use this code to override the **tempname** function, using the **php://temp** wrapper instead. This could go into a PHP file **overrides.php** (with any other overrides):

*overrides.php*

```
override_function('tempname', '', 'return override_tempname();');

function override_tempname(){
    $filename = "";

    do {
        $filename = "php://temp/file-".rand(10000,99999).".tmp"
    } while (file_exists($filename));

    return $filename;
}
```

...which you can then include:

```
<?php include("overrides.php"); ?>
```

In the PHP files you want to use the overrides in (or all files).

Comment: I had no idea `override_function()` existed. Thank you!